# Problema al convertir Ñ a ñ con php

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, mysqli

Resulta que estoy extrayendo de mi base de datos unos nombres que tienen Ñ y los convierto con php la primera en mayuscula y resto en minuscula, resulta que cuando se encuentra con la Ñ no me la convierte en minuscula dejandola de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el script que uso para convertir el nombre:

```html
function cambiarNombre(){
  $nombres = explode(" ", $_SESSION['user']['nombre']);
 $apellidos= explode(" ", $_SESSION['user']['apellido']);
 for($i=0; $i<=count($nombres); $i++){
  $nombre_completo.= ucfirst(strtolower($nombres[$i]));
  $nombre_completo.=" ";
 }
 for($i=0; $i<=count($apellidos); $i++){
  $nombre_completo.= ucfirst(strtolower($apellidos[$i]));
  $nombre_completo.=" ";
 }
 return $nombre_completo;
}
```

Por cierto este nombre esta en mayus en mi base, y trate en poner solo la Ñ en minus pero nada no funciona, la sigue poniendo mayus.

No se que pueda ser o que debo hacer, agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Has probado con la función  str_replace ( "Ñ" , "ñ" , $nombres ) ; ??

Comment: @YORS gracias por tu sugerencia, me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si es en PHP, puedes usar la función [mb_strlower()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtolower.php) del set de [funciones de caracteres multibyte](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.mbstring.php) `mb_*` donde puedes especificar un encoding.

```
<?php
$var = "ÁREA DE BAÑOS";
echo strtolower($var); // Área de baÑos
// si no se especifica, se usa una codificacion interna
echo mb_strtolower($var); // área de baños
// encoding utf-8
echo mb_strtolower($var, 'UTF-8'); // área de baños
```

Según [los comentarios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-strtolower.php#78906) de la página de PHP parece que `mb_string()` es más lento que hacer un `str_replace()`, lo cual hay que tomar en consideración si el script procesará miles de datos en corto tiempo o strings muy grandes.

En ese caso, parecido a como propone @YORS, podrías hacer algo como:

```
<?php
$var = "ÁREA DE BAÑOS";
$upp = array('Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú', 'Ü', 'Ñ');
$low = array('á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'ü', 'ñ');
echo str_replace($upp, $low, strtolower($var)); // área de baños
```

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza [mb_convert_case](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mb-convert-case.php).

`mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");`

El primer parámetro es la cadena que quieres convertir.

El segundo parámetro indica si quieres convertir a MAYÚSCULAS, minúsculas o Capitalizadas. (MB_CASE_UPPER, MB_CASE_LOWER, o MB_CASE_TITLE)

El tercer parámetro es la codificación de caracteres que requieras.

Tu función se resumiría a lo siguiente:

`function cambiarNombre(){
  $nombres  = $_SESSION['user']['nombre'];
  $apellidos= $_SESSION['user']['apellido'];
  return mb_convert_case(trim($nombres . ' ' . $apellidos),  MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
}`